# Search and Echo text (PHP)

Tags: php

how can I put together PHP code to look for a particular text string and then ECHO that string.

Example this is the code on the website

```
<input id="marketingform_input_aidcformularioawarenessgeneral_email" name="marketingform[email]" value="" placeholder="Email" class="marketingform-input" type="email">
```

and I want the php code look for the text inside the string

```
name="marketingform[email]"
```

and the Echo that text:

> marketingform[email]

Answer (score 0):

If the form's method is `post`, you can access it via the `$_POST` variable. If the form's method is `get` (or not specified), you can access it via the `$_GET` variable. Field names with brackets are expanded into arrays:

```
$email = $_POST['marketingform']['email'];
```

You can `print_r($_POST)` (or `$_GET`) to see what it contains and how the various fields in the form are accessible.

Comment: ...or `$_REQUEST` (just saying)

Comment: @Martin yes, but that also includes `$_COOKIE` and most servers are configured to fill `$_REQUEST` in the order `$_GET`, then `$_POST`, then `$_COOKIE`, so a form's values in `$_REQUEST` can be overridden if you have a cookie with the same name as a form field. I would never recommend its use to beginning PHP developers.

Comment: Oh no it's not recommended, but I saw you'd referenced `$_GET` so might as well reference request as well